# Which is best/efficient for maintaining in-app documentation in a web app: xml, INI, DB, other?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, ini

**Background:** I'm building a small application at the moment, but I'm at a point where I'm slowly adding documentation into the interface, e.g. instructions, how-to's etc.

I'm wondering if there's an effective approach to centralizing the documentation so that dealing with issues like:

1. localization
2. Editing/maintenance
3. Reference/cross-referencing, etc

is a little easier.

I've considered throwing it all into a dedicated table in my DB, but I would really prefer to minimize DB queries to only the essential/non-trivial data. I've considered INI files, but I'm concerned about long-term maintenance; likewise with XML.

Out of all of the options I'd likely choose XML for both portability and cross-referencing. If anyone has had similar experiences with this issue, I would really love to know what approach you took.

Answer (score 0):

> I would really prefer to minimize DB queries to only the essential/non-trivial data.

What for?
There is not a single reason to do that.

> but I'm concerned about long-term maintenance; likewise with XML.

Exactly you are.

Database is the only way to go. XML is a *data-interchange* format and ini files used to store settings, not data

Comment: Ok, so if I update the documentation and want to update several instances of the app--how would I depoly the updates if they were in a DB?

Comment: @user just retrieve these documents from db

Comment: Thank you for responding--I do appreciate your responses; however, I'm looking a solid rationale for choosing one option over another.

Comment: @user haha, as you wish. To me this question is like "what woud you use to eat a soup - a spoon, a fork or a stick", with obvious answer. However, you can make yourself an occupation in searching such a "solid rationale" for such a trivial question :)

Comment: wow. I don't see that  there's absolutely nothing wrong with seeking rationale rather than settling for convention. And quite frankly I'm not about to accept your convention on the basis that *you* say so. Pls keep this productive...